# Is there any way to disable two finger scroll in MAC just for a single web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In web app, at the end of scroll using two fingers, instead of leaving the page, user should stay in the page. 
Is there any way to disable the default behaviour using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this by identifying the OS**

```
var mac = window.navigator.platform.toUpperCase().includes('MAC')>=0;

if (mac) {
  document.getElementById('container').style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
```